# Autowiring an interface that has neither a @Component, a @Service nor a @Repository implementation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I encountered this and doesn't throw an error and works fine at runtime but always calls the **class A** implementation:

```
public interface IA {
    void foo();
}

public class A implements IA 
{
   void foo() {...}
}

public class B implements IA
{
   void foo() {...}
}

@Service
public class FooService
{
   @Autowired private IA ia;

   public void foo() {
      ia.foo();
   }
}
```

Can someone help explain why this works?

EDIT:

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {...})
public class ApplicationConfig
{
...
}
```

Comment: Why it should not work. Do you have a spring XML configuration?

Comment: Can you show the configuration xmls / annotations used ? Is there any component scanning enabled? Can you show the configurations from web.xml and associated spring xml files or the equivalent files [for servlet 3.0 applications]

Comment: There is a component scan enabled in annotation in ApplicationConfig. But I thought the idea is that only classes annotated with @Component/@Service/@Repository can be autowired? Above IA is not annotated with any of those as well as the A and B implementation. But it works, I'd like to know why?

Comment: This should not be possible given the code that you are supplying. Check your config again, something makes Spring create a bean for `A`, Spring doesn't just go about dong stuff without you telling it to.

Comment: @Tobb, that's what I thought. Turns out `FooService` was never used. Class `A` 'foo()' was directly called. But it's just a weird code why `FooService` is even implemented this way. I'm gonna notify the one who implemented this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: To update this and clarify the solution. `IA` was declared somewhere down the `ApplicationConfig` file with a `@Bean` annotation that's why there's no error.